# How to remove the untrusted certificate window when connecting to RDP?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, remote-desktop, rdp

I use AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting.
So I'm connecting:

```
        _rdp.Server = "";
        _rdp.UserName = "";
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = "";

        _rdp.ColorDepth = 24;
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.SmartSizing = true;
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 2;
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
        
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectDevices = true;
        _rdp.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectDrives = true;

        _rdp.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualWidth);
        _rdp.Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualHeight);
        _rdp.DesktopWidth = Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualWidth);
        _rdp.DesktopHeight = Convert.ToInt32(this.ActualHeight);
```

where _rdp is:

```
class RdpControl : AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting
{
    public RdpControl() : base() { }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        // Fix for the missing focus issue on the rdp client component
        if (m.Msg == 0x0021 && !this.ContainsFocus) // WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
            this.Focus();

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpclientnonscriptable4-markrdpsettingssecure) in the msdn documentation, but for some reason this property is not in AxMsRdpClient.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yaZR.png

Comment: Use a properly issued certificate maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit stupid. Because I found the answer while rereading my question xD.

It is necessary to set the Authentication Level property to 0, or simply delete it:

```
_rdp.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 0;
```